# What's the translation of “crisscross" in French?

Tags: traduction

[Example of the use of *crisscross* in English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darjeeling#/media/File:Darjeeling_Himalayan_Railway.jpg):

[image]

From [Strongdar](https://www.reddit.com/user/Strongdar) on [Reddit](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/285542/3023):

> In that context, crisscross would tell you that it crosses the street repeatedly, in a back and forth sort of manner. Cross would just mean it goes over the street once.

What's the translation of “crisscross" in French on this context?

---

[translate.google.com](https://translate.google.com/?sl=en&tl=fr&text=crisscrosses&op=translate) says that the translation of “crisscross" in French is *croiser*, however *croiser* is also the transition of *cross*, as https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais-anglais/croiser/20503 mentions:

[image]

Comment: Instead of focusing on the meanings of *croiser*, it might have been more helpful to better explain the meanings and usages of crisscross in English, with more examples.

Comment: Dans quel contexte?

Comment: @Gilles'SOnousesthostile' context of the caption

Comment: Please explain the meaning in English, and preferably make it accessible to people who can't see pictures. I find “crisscross” strange in this context: it applies to 2-dimensional objects, but a street is mostly one-dimensional. Does it mean that the tracks keep changing sides?

Comment: @Gilles'SOnousesthostile' yes it means that the tracks keep changing sides.

Comment: This is not good English. Crisscross is odd in this context in English.

Comment: @JamesK odd because the presence of curves, or something else?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Odd because "criss-cross" has the sense "many straight lines crossing each other: up until the time of the Revolution this crisscross grid of walls in the landscape gradually occupied most of the communal perimeter — In addition to airlines , power grids , highways , railroads , post offices , telephones , radio and television , gas pipelines , oil pipelines which crisscross [ it ] , there are many more networks —The Paris subway (le métro) opened in 1900 and today includes 365 stations on fifteen lines that crisscross each other.

Comment: @LPH got it, thanks for straigthening that up!

Comment: Please note: The English in the picture is not right. This question was asked on ELL, and it is very simple. No train can "crisscross a street". So, to ask for a translation of a misused term in English is really too much. The train is **snaking** its way down the street. And most of the answers here **reflect** that. snaking is curvy, crisscrossing is not.

Comment: (https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/285540/3023)

Answer (score 6):

For a line that keeps going in the same general direction, but wobbles back and forth, the verb that comes to mind is *[sinuer](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sinuer)*.

> La voie étroite sinue le long de la rue.

Another possibility is *[serpenter](https://cnrtl.fr/definition/serpenter)*, which means to move with an undulating motion like a snake. *Serpenter* is close to “slither” in English, but only refers to the shape of the movement, it doesn't have any other snake-like connotation. Strictly speaking I guess the unmoving track *sinue* and the moving train *serpente* but in practice the two are largely interchangeable.

> La voie étroite serpente le long de la rue.

Or you can just say that it keeps crossing from one side of the street to the other.

> La voie étroite longe la rue en la traversant en de nombreux endroits.

> La voie étroite passe sans cesse d'un côté de la rue à l'autre.

Comment: *Sinuer* or *serpenter* would be [*to snake*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/snake#Verb) in English, not *to slither*.

Comment: « Le long de » ne signifie pas spécifiquement « dans » : « Un sentier sablonneux serpentait le long du canal. ».

Comment: Il est à noter à quel point tout le monde ici comprend que l'anglais ne va pas. Un train ne peut pas crisscross a street. Par contre, serpenter c'est bien l'idée.

Comment: @Lambie: A train can crisscross a river. From Google books: "Following and crisscrossing the scenic Noyo River, the little train crosses 44 bridges and descends 1364 feet before it reaches sea level at Fort Bragg." Why not a street? These are two different meanings of *crisscross*, but they're both perfectly valid in English.

Comment: @PeterShor I feel a difference between these two cases: a train that crisscrosses a river crosses the river all the way each time, whereas in the case of the question here the train is just changing sides but staying on the street. Would you say that a boat crisscrosses a river if it's travelling alongside the river and shifting from one bank to the other?

Comment: @PeterShor My dear friend, but oeuf corse. That is nothing like that Himalayan train at all. Why not a street? Because most "trains" (railway coaches as they say in India), even narrow gauge, would not FIT across a street. Take a look at this map here: the train winds its way through the landscape: so cute: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darjeeling_Himalayan_Railway#/media/File:DHR_Route_Map.jpg

Comment: If it stops repeatedly on each bank (the way the tram presumably does), I'd use *criss-cross*. If it's just meandering down the river without stopping, probably not.

Comment: The original picture posted in the original question is very "misleading". One can clearly see that the bulk of the train takes up the whole street. Also, trams and suchlike either run on straight or curved tracks over a long-ish distance.

Answer (score 3):

Knowing this type of rall line prior to this question (for example : [the tram n°28 in Lisbon](https://goo.gl/maps/4S9RZUWEuA4QwFy96)), the first idea that come to my mind was :

- [**serpenter**](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/serpenter). "Former, décrire une ligne sinueuse"

> Le petit train serpente d'un bord à l'autre de la chaussée.

But, after thinking about it, some people would probably use the less formal and less accurate (curves are not zigzags)

- [**zigzaguer**](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/zigzaguer) "Marcher, avancer en faisant des zigzags"

> Le tramway zigzague d'un bord à l'autre de la chaussée.

Finally, reading the question again, it seems the verb crisscross here is describing the way the rails, due to their curve, are crossing the main flow of the street multiple times. The closest verb in that sense would be:

- **[s'entrecroiser](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/entrecroiser)**

but the sentences with this verb seem less fluid :

> La ligne s'entrecroise avec la circulation à de nombreuses reprises.

Comment: @Pasunclue They're just examples but anyway I adjust them to the present tense.

Comment: Absolument, et très bien parce que l'anglais devrait être to snake. Et non pas crisscross.

Answer (score 2):

A verb I found while using [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sillonner#French) that could (potentially) be used here is [***sillonner***](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/sillonner/72766), though not being a native French speaker I don't know how formal/informal this word is nor if it applies in this context.

Comment: https://www.deepl.com/translator#en/fr/to%20crisscross%0A : **to  crisscross → s'entrecroiser** (se croiser et se croiser à nouveau en différents endroits), cela peut se faire en *sillonnant* les rues.

Comment: _Sillonner_ typically involves many parallel lines ([sillons](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/sillon)). I don't think it works in this context. Then again, I wouldn't use _crisscross_ in English here either: to me this involves lines that cross each other.

Answer (score 2):

For this very example :

- La ligne de chemin de fer empruntait la rue, tantôt à droite tantôt à gauche.

Answer (score 1):

This is a complex situation, that is not being rendered precisely by a single term, and there is no fixed expression for that. "Serpenter" and "sinuer" are proper terms for the description of curved lines in general, but in this particular case saying that the track "serpente"  in the street sounds vague: a street is something which, specially in old urban agglomerations, is not so rarely found to snake through the town or through  a neighbourhood; so possibly one might ask oneself whether what was meant could not be that the track snaked through the neighbourhood  along with the street. A clear rendering of the proper term—if there is a proper term, as user [James K](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/45472/whats-the-translation-of-crisscross-in-french#comment92614_45472) noticed "crisscross" does not appear to be a good choice—should involve a little description. Something as what follows would leave little doubt in the reader's mind.

- La voie ferrée serpente dans la rue, la traversant obliquement pour passer tour à tour d'un côté à l'autre, ne longeant jamais ni l'un ni l'autre que sur une courte distance.

"que sur une courte distance" can be eliminated, replaced or modified to fit exactly the particular case; other modifications can be made (for instance the negative "ne … jamais" can be removed so as to have an affirmative form, etc.)

If after a crossing from one side to the other the track keeps running along this given side over a distance that is long enough, then I think that describing it as a meandering track is not very meaningful.

- la voie ferrée longe tantôt un côté de la rue tantôt l'autre, qu'elle atteint simplement en la traversant (au niveau de la chaussée).

"au niveau de la chaussée" can be added at the end to make clear there are no bridges or tunnels.

Comment: Thanks, great ideas!

Comment: @Pasunclue Right, the present fits the case better; I change that; thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: crisscross is misused in the English, as I spent a lot of time explaining when he asked the question on ELL. Funny how you instinctively go to serpenter, and the English should be snake. Comme je me fatigue à répéter, aucun train peut: crisscross a street. C'est impossible puisque aucun train traverse une rue en faisant des angles carrés.

Comment: @Lambie: *Crisscross* is not misused in the English. It can mean what you think it means, but it can also mean what the OP thinks it means. See [Lexico](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/45472/whats-the-translation-of-crisscross-in-french): Move or travel around (a place) by going back and forth repeatedly. For example (from Google books) "Following and crisscrossing the scenic Noyo River, the little train crosses 44 bridges and descends 1364 feet before it reaches sea level at Fort Bragg."

Comment: @PeterShor That Himalayan "milk car" is not crisscrossing a street. It can barely fit on the tracks going down the street. And that map that was produced to show its routes, is a snaking route. Consider: He crisscrossed the street, stopping at every single store he saw. A train cannot do that within the confines of a street. Come now. Now, a train may have a crisscross pattern over a large area, but not in the confines of a street. Whoops, I am repeating myself. One could say: The NYC subway system crisscrosses the city....right?

Comment: @PeterShor The definition in lexico makes clear that the lines must intersect (that is to say not the mathematical lines, but the "physical" segments): "Form a pattern of intersecting lines or paths on (a place) ‘the green hill was criss-crossed with a network of sheep tracks’ ". Moreover, you couldn't say that the train moved _around_ the street.

Comment: @LPH Tu vois? On est bien d'accord là. Au fond, le movement de crisscross pourrait également se dire zigzaguer. Un movement qu'un train ne fera pas non plus....à moins de visualiser les rails à une assez grande distance sur un terrain quelconque.